# linux/kmalloc_sizes.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c

I tried `locate kmalloc_sizes.h` but didn't find the file. And I used `apt-file` to search but couldn't find the package. How can I get this header file?

Comment: What makes you think that this file exists? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I'm trying to compile a project from other people, and it shows this error.

Comment: Do you have `locate` database? What linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you're looking for is actually called [kmalloc_sizes.h](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/include/linux/kmalloc_sizes.h).

You can get it by installing the Linux kernel headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files

Comment: Does that mean your problem is fixed now?

Comment: No, I still can't find that file.

Comment: @嬲你屋里娘 I've updated my answer with how to get it from `apt`.